# Delphi 2010 and Firebird 1.5

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, firebird

Can I continue to use the interbase vcl components in delphi 2010 with firebird 1.5?
Thanks

Comment: Why still using Firebird 1.5 ?

Comment: Because it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As IBX have to support legacy code for Interbase, it will work. Better, it still work with FB 2.1.
I think you should read this blog post.
http://compaspascal.blogspot.com/2009/08/why-to-use-firebirdibx.html

Also check comments for one update that you will need to make in IBX sources if you will work with non default or Unicode Charsets and Collations.

Comment: You are wellcome =]. But surely you should think about upgrade your databases. This could give you some work, but would be worth to do it. In most of cases, i think, you will need nothing more than few days to do it.

Answer (score 5):

We've used the IBX components in Delphi 2010 with FB 1.5 and 2.1, no problems - both embedded and client/server versions of Firebird.

We had a large legacy app in D7 that used IBX and IB6.01, we didn't have the resources to go and redevelop the whole thing using dbx so had a go with the newer version of IBX and Firebird and it went like a dream.

The only gotchas we had were to do with UDFs; we had written a few Interbase UDFs of our own that conflicted with newer, built-in functions etc in Firebird. I was happy to drop our UDFs and use the 'official' ones!

Comment: Consider UIB and FIB+ - they are more in design like IBX. Though is it "just works" then converting might be redundant. DBX is not nice substitution: it looses events and some argue that native components like UIB can have 3x throughput than COM-based DBX.
However IBX has nice extension library i referenced below.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the Interbase components, but I've been able to successfully use Firebird under D2010 with DB Express.  I used the DBX driver found at http://sites.google.com/site/dbxfirebird/.

Comment: Which components do You use to work with fb1.5 an d2010? Thanks

Comment: if You have Delphi Client/Server and up, then stock interbase driver should work, unless you would use boolean and bigint types. // @Alejandro - there are 3 non-Embarcadero dbx drivers out there. The one mentioned - no source, no contacts, nothing. You can take it but you canot be sure it would always work good. And you cannot be sure it is not pirated one way or another. DevArt.com seems to offer most up to date one. And upscene.com to though it seems more expensive and less updated. Unified Interbas had side-project of developing DBX driver, but ceased. Note that POST_EVENT wouldn't go DBX

Answer (score 0):

D2010 with DbExpress seems to work well with Firebird.

Answer (score 0):

If it is still actually: The best components for Borland\CodeGear\Embarcadero Delphi (for 2010- or XE+) is "FIBPlus" http://devrace.com/en/fibplus/

Answer (score 0):

We still use IBX in our legacy application, though it gets hard. For example it does not support version check for Firebird. It does not suppoer EXECUTE BLOCK, INSERT RETURNING and so on.

Int64 (bigInt) type is also problematic, because Interbase has boolean type at that index instead.
But other than that it seem to work.

While generally we'd switch to Unified Interbase component set, for safety and better compatibility, for now it does not worth it.

I also suggest you IBX extension - download link is below: http://www.loginovprojects.ru/index.php?page=ibxfbutils